# Redux state updates two seperate objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have influencer data object. This object is beeing pulled from database with action `FETCH_INFLUENCER` and put inside two different objects: `influencer` and `formInfluencer` in redux store. And then I have action `SET_INFLUENCER` that is supposed to create new instance of the state and update `influencer` object in redux. For some reason though it updates both `influencer` and `formInfluencer`. I really struggle with finding answer here since I think I did everything to prevent pointing of two different variables to the same object and still it happens.

reducer:

```
    case 'FETCH_INFLUENCER_FULFILLED':
        return { ...state, fetching: false, fetched: true, influencer: action.payload.data, formInfluencer: Object.assign([], action.payload.data) }
    case 'SET_INFLUENCER':
        return { ...state, influencer: action.payload }
```

actions:

```
export function fetchInfluencer(id) {
return {
    type: "FETCH_INFLUENCER",
    payload: axios.get('/api/influencer/' + id, {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')}})
}
}
export function setInfluencer(influencer) {
return {
    type: "SET_INFLUENCER",
    payload: influencer
}
}
```

dispatch:

```
 handleUserChange(e) {
    let influencer = [...this.props.influencer]
    influencer[0].user[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.props.dispatch(setInfluencer(influencer))
}
```

mapping state to props:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
    influencer: state.influencers.influencer,
    formInfluencer: state.influencers.formInfluencer
}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(InfluencerDetails)
```

If You have any idea why this could be happening I would be happy to hear the answer.

Comment: `influencer[0].user[e.target.name]` this mutates props, which is forbidden in React.

Comment: Which is probably the reason why it updates both object in your store.

Comment: I thought creating copy of props with `let influencer = [...this.props.influencer]` prevents mutating. So what would be the way to fix this? I am kind of out of ideas with this one if You have answer or a hint.

Comment: Also this props is assigned directly to redux `state.influencer` and not `state.formInfluencer` so I thought this shouldn't be an issue. hmm Guess I have some misunderstanding in mutation topic.

Comment: `influencer = [...this.props.influencer]` makes a **shallow**  copy of this.props.influencer; its contents are still the same references as in the original, so influencer[0] is still the same reference as this.props.influencer[0], and mutating influencer[0].user still mutates that state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't mutate state (if you don't mutate it, then it is no problem that you have multiple variables pointing to the same object).

Instead of:

```
handleUserChange(e) {
    let influencer = [...this.props.influencer]
    influencer[0].user[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.props.dispatch(setInfluencer(influencer))
}
```

You should do a bit more work:

```
handleUserChange(e) {
    const newUser = {
        ...this.props.influencer[0].user,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    };
    const newInfluencer = {
        ...this.props.influencer[0],
        user: newUser
    };
    const newInfluencers = [...this.props.influencer];
    newInfluencers[0] = newInfluencer;

    this.props.dispatch(setInfluencer(newInfluencers));
}
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue. Thank You! But I would like to ask about a step here I don't really understand. From what I see we are making here a new `const` which makes a copy of user and adds provided value. Then we do the copy of influencer object itself and assign newUser to it. But I wonder what is this step doing in this case: `const newInfluencers = [...this.props.influencer];`

Comment: Oh I now read it correctly. So this step just makes a new const which is a copy of original influencer object and assigns newInfluencer to it. So this is kind of a walkaround of the mutating I have done. Still if You have a better explenation of what is happening here I would love to hear that.